# Induction Approach for Coefficent/Exponent Problem

Tags: proof-explanation, induction

There is a problem I'm working that diverges quite a bit from the ramp up problems I had with induction.  Anyway, here it is:

> You have (mx+ny)$^g$ and g is an element in the natural numbers $\Bbb N$.
>
> What will the coefficient of x$^h$y$^g$$^-$$^h$ is g when h $\in$
> $\Bbb N$ and 0 $\le$ h $\le$ g

I'm struggling even at the base case, and I'm stuck on the approach you'd use to solve this.  Can this be approached some way other than induction as well?

**Base Case**

- Just going with h=1,g=2 you get m$^2$x$^2$+2mn xy + n$^2$y$^2$  There the coefficient is 2, so an initial suspicion would be the coeff. is related to the exponent g.  If you carry  that forward for h=2, g=3, the coefficient is 3 and so on. When the two (g and h) are the same value, the coefficent seems to be the evaluated value of y because the exponent on y is 0 and so the value is 1.   Does the base case need to be split up?

**Inductive Hypothesis**

- This will naturally depend on what the base case is.  I would think I'd want to prove this for k+1, but I struggle with what that should look like or if it would be split because of cases.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Cf. [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by reducing the problem - let $m = n = 1$, so that we're just expanding out $(x + y)^g$. Then, try expanding out a few more cases:

$$\begin{eqnarray}(x + y)^0 & = & 1 = 1 x^0 y^0 \\
(x + y)^1 & = & x + y \\
(x + y)^2 & = & x^2 + 2xy + y^2 \\
(x + y)^3 & = & x^3 + 3x^2 y + 3x y^2 + y^3 \\
(x + y)^4 & = & x^4 + 4x^3 y + 6 x^2 y^2 + 4 x y^3 + y^4 \end{eqnarray}$$

So it looks like the coefficients go something like:

$\begin{eqnarray}
&&&& 1 \\
&&& 1 && 1 \\
&& 1 && 2 && 1 \\
& 1 && 3 && 3 && 1\\
1 && 4 && 6 && 4 && 1
\end{eqnarray}$

Does this look like anything you're familiar with?

Comment: thank you!   Binomial Theorem/Pascal's Identity!